# Show div based on custom meta value

Tags: custom-field

I've search all over for a solution to this but can't seem to find anything that does exactly what I want it to.

Basically what I want to do is display a particular div within a post based on the value of a specific custom field.

For example;

If the value of the "featured" custom field is "1" then I want to be able to show a div within single.php for that particular post

But if the value of the "featured" custom field is anything other than 1 then I don't want anything to appear.

Does that makes sense?

Comment: How are you adding this particular `<div>` to the post? Or is your question more like "How do I add a `<div>` to a post based on a meta field value?"

Comment: It would be added to the end of the post. So if the meta value is '1' then "sample-div" would be added after all the user created conent

Comment: Have you searched [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)? Have you tried to implement any of those examples into your theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need a filter on `the_content`.

```
function add_conditional_div($content) {
    global $post;
    $meta_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your-field-name', true);
    if (1 === $meta_field) {
        $content .= '<div>whatever</div>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

The `1` value, of course, is whatever should match your meta_field.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

You could also edit your theme files directly or make a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). The latter is highly encouraged if you are editing a theme you didn't create.

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. I don't actually want it to be part of the content, just to come after the loop

Comment: @DeanElliott, your description of the problem in your question does not match the comment you just posted. "div within a post based on the value of a specific custom field" strongly implies _in the Loop_ not after it.